# start applet in a website

Tags: java, web, applet, japplet

Good Morning

I created i JApplet Java gamemenu, with eclipse everything works just fine in with the debugger. But now i want to release it and i got some Problems.

I found many different ways to integrate a Applet in a website.

```
<applet archive="rest.jar" code="Startseite.class" width="1200" height="600">
</applet>
```

or

```
<applet code="MenuTest.src.klassen" archive="rest.jar"></applet>
```

or

```
<object codetype="application/java-archive"classid="java:Startseite.class"
   width="400" height="300">
</object>
```

1. First of all, which of these posibilities is the best way to include an Applet in a  Website.
2. Wenn i try to open the html file with any of these codes, there is an Java Error about an "Security settings who blocked this Runnable code". 
   Is this a Problem with the Firewall, or with Java itself?

thanks very much

BBallBoy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://www.java.com/en/download/help/java_blocked.xml

Hello
Good question I recently ran in to this myself. You need to add an exception for your app in the java control panel security settings.

Steps to Add URLs to the Exception Site list
Go to the Java Control Panel (On Windows Click Start and then Configure Java)
Click on the Security tab
Click on the Edit Site List button
Click Add in the Exception Site List window

Add url to Exception Site list
Click in the empty field under the Location field to enter the URL

Example: http://www.example.com
(URL should begin with http:// or https://)

If the URL where the applet is hosted is different from the URL of the web page from which the applet is launched, then you will need to add both the URL for the applet as well as the URL for the web page.

Example with different URLs for the applet and the web page
For Yahoo games Checkers, you would enter both URLs (The urls listed can be different depending on which host is serving the game)
http://www.games.yahoo.com
This is the url for the Yahoo games domain
http://yog36.games.sp2.yahoo.com
This is the url where the game is hosted and shown in the dialog box for the blocked application

Click OK to save the URL that you entered
Click Continue on the Security Warning dialog
Applications where this issue has been reported

Comment: Ah Great, i already set the Security settings on medium, but this wasn't enough.
So now the class is loading, but i have the next issue...
i get an Error with the "Java.oi.Filepermission".
I can't read my Image Files. You have an idea?
thx

Comment: Hello. What operating system are you using(win 8)? First of all if you go to "configure java" instead of just the java control panel you will get extra security options. So when you are on the security tab click on the "Edit Site List button". Then run your applet again. Copy the url that appears in the browser when you run your applet. Now go back to the java control panel screen and paste the url in to the "Click Add in the Exception Site List window". This way the applet will always run and you won't have to lower the security settings on your computer.

Comment: I'm not sure about the image. Is it in the JAR or stored on computer somewhere?

Comment: i don't know if its also in the JAR, its not working with and without the JAR. The image is in a subfolder of the class.
I don't know if i have to give extra permission...

Comment: well maybe you have the wrong url in the applet. eg. resources/images/myImage.pgi

Comment: I found the error, i loaded the image with "getImage()" this command lead to the wrong directory, i solved the issue with getResourceStream(). :)
Now i have a NullPointer Ecxeption, but this must be an other problem, thx a lot :D